# Centered motion tracking with Mocha AE/Pro and After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, cc-2014

I haven't been able to figure out yet how I get stabilized footage from mocha Pro to After Effects.
I start a new project, import my footage and am able within mocha Pro to get a nice motion tracking and stabilizing it, so it always remains centered in the frame.

How do I get this data to After Effects so the motion tracking is centered as well? If I hit `Export Stabilized Tracking Data...` and paste it to my footage layer, it isn't as stabilized as what mocha Pro is able to do.

The reason I want it back in After Effects is to increase the canvas size as mocha Pro crops the footage because it moves the footage around.

The idea is to make something like [this](http://gfycat.com/DapperSpicyAmericancrayfish) or [this](http://gfycat.com/ComplexNaiveAbyssiniancat).

Is there a better way doing this than After Effects/mocha?

Comment: What are the differences between what you see in Mocha and what you see in AE.  It sounds like you are doing things correctly (the intended output of Mocha is generally a motion track), but without more description of the problem, it is going to be hard to tell where it is failing.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://imgur.com/a/ZVN4V#0) the After Effects (third) is much more shaky/unstable than the mocha Pro version (second). The first is the original footage. I stabilized in mocha Pro, hit the export within the stabilize module and pasted it to the footage in After Effects. No other changes have been made. I tried to track his face.

Comment: That is very odd indeed.  It looks like the magnitude of the motion effect got doubled somehow, but I have no idea how that could have happened.